# Using int as void pointer in C++

Tags: c++, void-pointers

There is a C++ snippet which has to use some old plain C *event_handler* functions.

The event_handler has this common signature:

```
add_event_handler(event_cb callback, void* user_data)
```

Note: `event_cb` is a function pointer, probably unrelated to this question.

`user_data` is defined to let the user to pass some extra information to the callback.

Now, my question is really simple, (how) can I pass a simple number as *user_data*?

```
add_event_handler(mycallback, 1); // compilation error
```

Obviously, because `1` is not a void*, but still, how can I pass some simple variable from the stack (not from heap)?

For example: is the below code considered correct?

```
int param=1;
add_event_handler(mycallback, &param);
```

Because this is working, but if I have to register more handlers, will look very ugly:

```
int param1=1;
int param2=2;
...
add_event_handler(mycallback, &param1);
add_event_handler(mycallback, &param2);
```

I just want to define the same callback for a bunch of events and give them an integer or enum value as *user_data* to decide about the necessary action in *mycallback*.

Here is *mycallback*:

```
static void mycallback(void* user_data) {
  // do an action based on user_data, ie: if 1 passed, print "one", if 2 print "two".
}
```

Please note: I've tried searching for these kind of things, but `void*` topic is huge, and Google was not that smart to understand my wishes. Sorry if there is another question here with the same topic, I haven't found that either. In this case please just post it, and mark this as *duplicate*.

Comment: How is this `user_data` argument used and processed? Does the `add_event_handler` do anything but store the argument? Does the "callback" function receive this as an argument itself, unmodified? If possible, please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Added `mycallback`. I don't unfortunately know what `add_event_handler` does with the user_data parameter, because it's closed source.

Comment: You'll need to cast `int` to `::std::intptr_t` and then to `void *`.

Comment: If this is an API as usual, then you need to know what `event_cb callback` is for, otherwise the discussion is futile. If you do not know, you have no way of using the knowledge of the answer to your question.

Comment: `typedef void (*event_cb)(void *user_data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***If*** (and only if) the `user_data` pointer isn't used elsewhere, you can use casting to convert any integer whose `sizeof` is smaller than (or equal to) `sizeof(void*)` to a `void*` type.

However, to be fully compliant you can't do the cast in a single step, it has to be done over an intermediate cast:

```
add_event_handler(mycallback, reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(1)));
```

To be able to use this you need to do the opposite casting:

```
static void mycallback(void* user_data) {
    int value = static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(user_data));
}
```

Casting like this is usually considered bad, but in some cases (like the one you have) it's really the only possible way to pass plain integer values.

<sub>[Note that on a 32-bit system with 32-bit pointers, a 64-bit integer type like `long long` can't be passed this way]</sub>

---

The other solution is, as you noted in your question, to use separate variables (or possibly dynamically allocated values) to be able to pass actual pointers.

Answer (score 1):

There's a convention that you map such handlers to C++ classes as follows:

1. The `user_data` points to an instance of a class
2. The callback is a `static` method of this class
3. The callback casts `user_data` back to a class pointer and calls the real callback method using this pointer.

Your `int` value would become the single member of this class. The advantage is that when you need another value, you can just add another member to the class.

Comment: I know this concept, but now the class is singleton, no need to pass the instance and I also don't want to have more than only one instance.